# Facebook share_open_graph error: "Invalid Action Link URL: The post's action links must be valid URLs."

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I have a site where I am trying to set up a Facebook Share button for a custom object. The custom object is created successfully. I can verify object creation in the Object Browser with owner as the custom app and type as the custom object type.

The call to FB.ui is successful, a dialog is opened that contains the correct data for the custom object. Upon clicking the **Post To Facebook** button, I get the error, "Invalid Action Link URL: The post's action links must be valid URLs."  The JSON response has an error_code value of 1349119.

### JS Code:

```
function PostStatus(id, qtext) {
    var msg = $(id).val();  
    var o = {'object': {"og:title" : qtext, "og:description": msg}, 'access_token': '<% = AccessToken %>'};
    FB.api("app/objects/namespace:customobject",
    'POST',
    o,
    function(response){
        if (response.id){
            FB.ui({method: 'share_open_graph', 
                action_type: 'og.likes', 
                action_properties: JSON.stringify({object: response.id}),
                display: 'popup'
                }, function(response){}

            );
        }
    });
}
```

If I change the `response.id` value to `http://www.google.com`, I can successfully post to my wall.

### Response:

```
{
    "error_code" : 1349119,
    "error_message" : "Invalid+Action+Link+URL:+The+post's+action+links+must+be+valid+URLs."
}
```

I can't find a reference to this error code anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue that we are tracking in this bug report:
[sharing openGraph action type og.likes/og.shares fails with object id (needs url)](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/797322210351760/)